# Why are these outputs different?

Tags: ruby

These two have different output.

```
aArray = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]

aArray.each {|subArray| puts subArray}

aArray.each {|subArray| puts "#{subArray}"}
```

The first each statement prints all the numbers in the array individually while the second statement prints all the subArrays.

What magic does "#" do in this case?

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of headaches while learning Ruby if you stick with [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the example in your question is a nested hash makes not really a difference, therefore I will simplify your question to:

*Why do these two examples print different output?*

```
puts [1,2,3]
# 1
# 2
# 3

puts "#{[1,2,3]}"
# [1, 2, 3]
```

From the documentation of [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> [...] If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. Each given object that isn’t a string or array will be converted by calling its to_s method. [...]

That said:

```
puts [1,2,3]
```

is interpreted as:

```
[1,2,3].each do |element|
  puts element
end
```

What is basically the same as:

```
puts 1
puts 2
puts 3
```

and prints each element of the array in a line on its own.

Whereas your second example works differently:

```
puts "#{[1,2,3]}"
```

In a first step the string interpolation will happen. That means Ruby will evaluate the `"#{[1,2,3]}"` part. String interpolation is done by calling `to_s` on the expression within the `#{}`. Calling `[1,2,3].to_s` will return the string (not the array) `'[1,2,3]'`. This string is inserted into the outer string at the place of the interpolation. The result is one string that Ruby prints into one line in a second step. To illustrate each step:

```
puts "#{[1,2,3]}"
puts "#{[1,2,3].to_s}"
puts "#{'[1,2,3]'}"
puts "[1,2,3]"
# [1,2,3]
```

Comment: "Each given object that ISN'T a string or array will be converted by calling its to_s method", however, the subarray is also an array, so why is it converted to string representation?

Comment: A niggly: `puts 'hi'` invokes [Kernel#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html), which in turn invokes `$stdout.puts 'hi'`. As `$stdout.class #=> IO`, the method [IO#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) (which you reference) is invoked. We can see that it's `Kernel#puts` as follows: 
`Kernel.send(:remove_method, :puts); puts "hi" #=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'puts' for main:Object`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I tried to do subAarray.class (which returns array) and "#{subArray}".class(returns String), but the document says that if the objective is not array or string, then it will be convereted. However, since both of them are either array or string, why did "#{subArray}" gets converted?

Comment: @aDev I updated my answer to address your questions.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it. Since both of them are either string or array, I was confused by the document which states that : if the object is neither string and array, then it gets converted.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `puts` outputs each element of the array on its own line.

However,

```
puts "#{subArray}"
```

is equivalent to:

```
puts subArray.to_s
```

This [converts](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-inspect) the array to a *string representation of itself*; so the square brackets are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, **puts** method is used to output each element of the array in a line.

The #{} literal is the operator used for interpolation inside double-quoted strings. From a practical point of view, the expression inside the literal is evaluated, and then the entire #{} expression (including both the operator and the expression it contains) is replaced in situ with the result.

Comment: `puts` is a method, not keyword

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, was working on C++ and confused between the two.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the first one is the actual variable, and the second one is the variable in a string. The `#{}` makes it so you can put variables straight into the string without having to use the `.+()` or just `+`. Make sure to use double quotes when having the `#{}` because that signals to ruby that you are going to put a variable in, if you use single quotes it would actually print the `#{}` with the variable name.
For example:

```
name = "Origami"
puts '#{name}'
puts "#{name}"
```

The first one would print `#{name}`, but the second one would be: `Origami`